# Ionic Splash screen no se actualiza

Tags: ionic, splash

desarrollo una app en Ionic 1 (1.7.15), funciona todo correctamente, pero mi problema es que cambié el archivo splash.png (2208x2208) en la carpeta ***ionic/resources***, y ahora cuando ejecuto el comando **ionic resources**, la pantalla de bienvenida sigue mostrándose de acuerdo al archivo anterior.

**ionic cli: 1.7.15 - cordova cli: 6.3.1**

He probado removiendo la plataforma y agregándola, probé también con ionic --clean-cache y no he logrado actualizar la splah, les agradeceré si me orientan para resolver esto

Gracias !!!

Comment: Prueba colocando el splash en la carpeta www , luego referencia en el config.xml

Answer (score 1):

Si ocupaste photoshop para generar el splash, quita el "interlace" y prueba. A mí me funcionó con eso.